# don't understand the ia32e 4-level paging

Tags: kernel, x86-64, paging

I have recently studied the IA32e paging, and though I know how that works, when I came across a real example, I can't understand what the value in each entry presents.

I have read the manual, which told me there are a few flag bits to be set, and I tried to break down the value of PML4E, PDPTE, and PDE in the following example into the format written on the manual, but the result seems to be wrong.

```
//=======   init page
.align 8

.org    0x1000

__PML4E:

    .quad   0x102007
    .fill   255,8,0
    .quad   0x102007
    .fill   255,8,0

.org    0x2000

__PDPTE:
    
    .quad   0x103003
    .fill   511,8,0

.org    0x3000

__PDE:

    .quad   0x000083    
    .quad   0x200083
    .quad   0x400083
    .quad   0x600083
    .quad   0x800083
    .quad   0xe0000083      /*0x a00000*/
    .quad   0xe0200083
    .quad   0xe0400083
    .quad   0xe0600083      /*0x1000000*/
    .quad   0xe0800083
    .quad   0xe0a00083
    .quad   0xe0c00083
    .quad   0xe0e00083
    .fill   499,8,0
```

The code comes from the book <<一個64位操作系統的設計與實現>>*The Design and Implementation of a 64-bit OS*. The code is available in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/yifengyou/The-design-and-implementation-of-a-64-bit-os/blob/master/code/c16/16-1/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%B9%B3%E5%8F%B0/kernel/head.S#L206)

The kernel are loaded at memory 0x100000;__PML4E,  __PDPTE,  and __PDE are stored at offset 0x1000, 0x2000, 0x3000 relative to where kernel is loaded

but what i can not understand is that why there is a 0x102007 instead of 0x102000, 0x103003 instead of 0x103000, and the intricate value in __PDE.

Comment: The lower bits of every paging structure are reversed for flags or ignored since these structures require a minimum alignment and the final lower bits of the virtual address are not translated.  Is this what you were asking about?

Answer (score 3):

A PML4E with value `0x102007` is `0x102000 + FLAG_PRESENT + FLAG_WRITE + FLAG_USER` which sets the 512GiB region controlled by this entry to be writable and accessible to code with CPL > 0 (and mark the entry present).

A PDPTE with value `0x103003` is `0x102000 + FLAG_PRESENT + FLAG_WRITE` which sets the 1GiB region controlled by this entry to be writable but not accessible to code with CPL > 0 (and mark the entry present).

A PDE with value `0x000083` is `0x000000 + FLAG_PRESENT + FLAG_WRITE + FLAG_PAGESIZE` which makes the PDE directly map a writable 2MiB page that cannot be accessed by code with CPL > 0 (and mark the entry present).

Assuming paging is set up, these paging structures create the following memory map:

```
0               -  10MiB            Identity mapped as writable for the kernel
10MiB           -  26MiB            Mapped to 0xe0000000 as writable for the kernel
26MiB           -  1GiB             Not mapped
1GiB            -  512GiB           Not mapped
512GiB          -  64TiB            Not mapped
64TiB           -  64TiB + 512GiB   Alias to range 0 - 512GiB
64TiB + 512GiB  -  256TiB           Not mapped
```